# WebSql Transaction fall back not working

Tags: javascript, sqlite, transactions, web-sql

I'm using a transaction with multiples queries.
What I'd like is the transaction to fallback whenever one query fails.
I read that I had to *return true* in the transaction's error callback but it doesn't work.

Here is the code :

```
db.transaction(
            function(tx) {

                // First Query
                tx.executeSql("insert into groups ('name') VALUES ('TEST1')", [],
                    function(tx, results) { // Success CB
                        console.error("Q1 S");
                    },
                    function(tx, errObject) { // Error CB
                        console.error("Q1 E");
                    });

                // Second Query
                tx.executeSql("insert into groupss ('name') VALUES ('TEST2')", [],
                    function(tx, results) { // Success CB
                        console.error("Q2 S");
                    },
                    function(tx, errObject) { // Error CB
                        console.error("Q2 E");
                    });
            },

            // Tx error callback
            function(err, err2) { console.error("TX ERROR"); return true; }
        );
```

So I changed the table's name in the second transaction to make the transaction fail but here is the output (on Chrome) :

```
> Q1 S
> Q2 E
```

**Problem 1** : I don't get the error "TX ERROR" as expected

**Problem 2** : Q1 is persisted and not reverted.

Answer (score 0):

So I was doing it wrong.
The *return true* statement must be specified in the **query's error callback**, and not the tx's !